# Error al añadir dependencias a un proyecto Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

He creado un marven project mediante intellij sin ninguna plantilla, la cuestión es que no me deja añadir ningun tipo de dependencia puesto que lo que añado me lo marca como error, a continuación os muestro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El elemento `<dependencies>` está duplicado. Y `<build>` no va dentro de `<dependencies>`.

Answer (score 1):

La estructura del archivo `pom` no es correcta, dentro del tag `<dependencies>` no debe estar el `<build>` sino fuera de dicho bloque, es decir debería ser algo así:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mtx</groupId>
  <artifactId>cliente-servidor-ftp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- definición de versiones -->
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <!-- lista de dependencias -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- build -->
  <build>

    <!-- lista de plugins -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Referencia de la estructura que debe tener un archivo `pom` https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Introduction